# Do Haxe .hxml build configs support variables?

Tags: haxe, hxml

My Haxe build has several targets and I have to manually c/p changes to each target.  Can .hxml files handle variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can reduce duplication with `--each` and `--next`:

```
-main Example
-lib examplelib

--each
-neko bin/example.n

--next
-java bin/java

--next
-cpp bin/cpp32
-D HXCPP_M32

--next
-cpp bin/cpp64
-D HXCPP_M64
```